# Should I encapsulate the last `return` statement with `else { return ... }` if it is logically optional?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, if-statement, code-size

Which format is better in terms of speed, performance and machine code size?

Last `return` is encapsulated:

```
static bool MyClass::IsEqual(int A, int B)
{
    if (A == B)
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Last `return` is not encapsulated:

```
static bool MyClass::IsEqual(int A, int B)
{
    if (A == B)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If the compiler is not braindead, both should give identical code.

Comment: I doubt there is an objective argument one way or the other

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evit" - And they'll be compiled to the same exact code

Comment: Agreed. But if you are unsure compile it into ASM yourself and look at it.

Comment: Clearly the latter will compile faster because it has fewer characters ;) Of course, the end user doesn't care how long it took to compile.

Comment: `return A==B` ;-)

Comment: Seriously, I've seen a lot of code like `if(something) return true; else return false;` this is bad either way.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker and not only because it's an overdue (yes, one should really `return a == b`), but also because it confuses the compiler - see my answer.

Comment: Write whatever makes sense to a reader. If it makes a measurable difference in performance fix your compiler, not your code.

Comment: @hkBattousai The 1st form might issue a silly compiler warning of kind 'Not all codepaths return a value'. Otherwise I think the 2 forms should result in identical machine instruction sequences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which format is better in terms of speed, performance and machine code size?

They should all be identical or close to it.  Moreover, you've asked the wrong question.

A better question would be,

> Which should I prefer and why?

Bear in mind that C++ code was designed to be read by *humans*, not machines.  Given this, a primary motive for selecting one coding style over another should be how readable it is to humans.  As important as this consideration is, it's also unfortunately subjective.  The bottom line is you have to decide for yourself which is better, but the important bit is that you're asking the right questions for the right reasons and thought about the answer.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question - generate and look at assembler code. I bet the assembler code is identical - so no difference in performance.

I always remove `if/else` if possible, considering your example I'd do:

```
static bool MyClass::IsEqual(int A, int B)
{
    return (A == B);
}
```

But I know the real world examples are not as simple as this.

Answer (score 2):

Both code snippets should produce the exact same result, so that's not an argument for either of them.

What really decides which version to use is coding style. The `if`/`else` variant has the advantage that both branches are on the same logical layer. Sometimes that may be a good reason to write it this way.

Comment: Conceptually it may be that the other case makes more sense in some scenarios, e.g. for checking inputs first and then having the "normal" code path at the least indented level.

Comment: True but in this case it's just return statements and it's ugly that way. But I agree, for param validation leaving out the else is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The second form is slightly more readable, because it reduces the nesting level. There is absolutely no performance penalty for using one form or the other.

Comment: I would disagree. Keeping everything in a scope is more readable to me and also more maintainable. Returning merely (A == B) is the best solution though.

Comment: I assume that your code is a good deal more complex than what you are showing, so I am commenting only on the additional nesting of the second `return` statement. In particular, there is no point to use if-then-eles for something as simple as `return A == B;`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yeah, exactly, and also the 2nd form cannot generate false positives for increased warning levels (**which everybody uses, right?**) about returning without a value.

Comment: @BSull I am certain that the OP's code is not nearly that trivial. What do you mean by "keeping everything in scope"? What "scope" are you talking about?

Comment: In the scope of the if statement. Having returns in various places is less readable and can lead to bugs. If the if statement has an explicit else you are less likely to get in trouble if you add code or change other logic.

Comment: @BSull `if` statement has two separate scopes - for the `then` and for the `else` branch. Moreover, having a `return` at the end is better specifically in cases when you "add code or change other logic", because it reduces the chance of hitting the undefined behavior after running off the end of the function without a `return`.

Comment: That's why you shouldn't have return statements throughout your function in the first place.

Comment: @BSull That is a rather subjective statement: there are valid arguments for both sides. For example, if your function does error checking of your parameters at the top, and needs to return an error code if one of the parameters is wrong, not using a return statement right there at the top creates a level of nesting that is both unnecessary and misleading.

Comment: @BSull - I strongly disagree with your point about return statements. [C++ is not C or assembly language](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/118793)

Comment: I mentioned above in another answer that with parameter checking having an if without an else and return statements make sense but having them scattered throughout your function with explicit and non explicit elses you will be much more likely to forget to return on a path.